# Finding closest point to some arbitrary 3D coordinate

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms

I have a cloud of points (hundreds of them) in 3D space. Now I need to find the closest point to my chosen coordinate somewhere in that space.

Is there any algorithm that is more efficient than simply iterating over all the points, calculating distance to my arbitrary coordinate and choosing that with lowest value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic nearest-neighbour problem in three dimensions. I refer you to the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) page on it for more information.

In particular, efficient algorithms usually construct a tree from the cloud of given points, then determine where the chosen (queried) point would fit in that tree. The problem is then reduced to checking the distance to points in neighbouring leaf nodes, which is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that you store your points in an appropriate data structure (not just a list of points). See [Binary space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).